# What does "obsessive behavior" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "obsessive behavior" mean?

I'm a new learner so I'm confused with this words! Do you know what does it mean? Can you give me some examples?

Thanks for helping~

Comment: "obessive", or "obsessive"? If it's the former, it's a typo for the latter, which you can look up in a dictionary.

Comment: Technically, there's no such thing as obsessive behavior.  "Obsessive" refers to a mental fixation.  "Compulsive" refers to behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a spelling error in your question.

If you mean "obsessive" then it means that the person in question has a strong obsessive nature.

synonyms:   all-consuming, consuming, compulsive, dominating, controlling, obsessional, addictive ...

Examples of usage:

- He had an obsession with tiny details.
- She has an obsessive nature when it comes to finding faults.
- They had an obsession with growing tulips.